# 9Patch Not Built Correctly Intellij Community Edition

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have recently changed over from Intellij 11 to Intellij 13 Community Edition. I have built my project but it seems that the 9Patch images are not working as expected.

[image]

You can see from this shadow on the navigation drawer. The 9patch images where working fine in intellij 11 so I presume there is a problem with the IDE/build process rather than the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with intellij 13, feel free to vote for it [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-120474)